# I am having trouble adding a position absolute element into a div that has scroll. Is it possible without introducing bugs and issues?

Tags: html, css, position

So I have a container that has vertical scroll. Within this container I have x amount of inputs and if the user hovers over any of the inputs a tooltip will be shown hovering over on the rightside of input.

The issue that I am seeing is that the tooltips inside of the scrolling container can not have an absolute position that leaves the container. Meaning if the user scrolls over the top input the tooltip will cut off once it hits the top of the scroll container.

I have tried a bunch of things, but nothing seems to work to get this setup to work properly. Z-index does not seem to allow me to get out of the scrolling container.

Sorry this isn't a perfect example, but basically you can see that the tooltips are confined into scroll container:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/6aijimdf

Expected results:
I have a scroll area in which there is an absolute positioned element that will leave the scroll area when it overflows it.

Actual results:
I have a scroll area in which the absolute positioned element can not leave the scroll area when it overflows it.

Answer (score 2):

Since tool tip container is `position: relative` and `overflow: scroll`, there is no way an `position: absolute` element can leave it.

I think a better way to achieve your expectation is using javascript to controll the tool tip element's position, and using `position: fixed` for that.

Comment: Do you happen to know of a good example of how to use javascript to position the tooltip?